# ajax call does not trigger server side web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp.net web page in which I am trying to validate usernames while entering username through ajax call but the call returns undefined value and when I tried to debug it, I found that control does not reach server side web method code. The ajax call code is

```
$(function () {

    $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_txtUserName").change(checkUser);
});

function checkUser() {
    var usernm = $('#ContentPlaceHolder2_txtUserName').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AdminHome.aspx/CheckUser",
        data: { username: usernm },
        success: function (data) {
            //var data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            alert(data);
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_lblError").empty();
            if (data.d != "0") {
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder2_lblError").html(' That user name has already been taken');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

the server side code is as below

```
[WebMethod]
    public static int CheckUser(string username)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnect"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_CheckUserName", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            conn.Open();
            int result= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give full url like : `http://localhost:8095/AdminHome.aspx/CheckUser`

Comment: Or just add a forward slash to the URL: `/AdminHome.aspx/CheckUser`. You should look in your network requests and see if the request is performed and what URL is called.